# HTTP header says "no-cache" only in IE

Tags: iis-7, cache

I'm running IIS7 - and for some reason the HTTP headers indicate a cached page has been served (e.g. Firefox's Firebug shows 304 Not Modified) yet the same page in fiddler for an IE8 request it says:

```
GET http://mywebsite.com/templates/cw/css/k2.css
200 OK (text/css)
no-cache,max-age=604800
```

I've looked in my Applicationhost.config and I see:

Not to mention, firefox shows that the pages are cached. Does anyone have any ideas on this? My site is really slow on IE - hoping that getting caching turned on will help.